# Shell Script Segfault

Tags: shell, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to run the following function in a .sh file.

```sh
function run_test()
{
    local executable=$1
    BINNAME=$(basename ${executable})
    local LOGDIR=$2
    
    # Get the list of timestamps from the log file names in log directory 'LOGDIR'
    LIST_OF_TS=`ls $LOGDIR/*.gz | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' | awk -F'_' '{print $2}' | awk -F'.' 
    
    echo "Adding run of $executable to $RUNDIR/$BINNAME.dat"
    
    for i in $LIST_OF_TS; do
        gunzip -c $LOGDIR/*$i*.gz | sort -n
    done | $executable "$2" > $RUNDIR/$BINNAME.dat 
    echo "Finished $executable"
}
```

This  gives the error

```html
for i in $LIST_OF_TS;
do
    gunzip -c $LOGDIR/*$i*.gz | sort -n;
done
     11726 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) | $executable "$2" > $RUNDIR/$BINNAME.dat
```

When I remove the "$2", this works fine. My goal is to pass in $2 (or $LOGDIR) as an argument to $executable. I have no idea why this segfaults. Any advice?

Comment: `why this segfaults` Ask `$executable`. It's the problem that seg faults. Segfault is an internal program fault - it's a problem with the executable, not with your script. `When I remove the "$2", this works fine` most probably that program can't properly handle arguments.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thanks